# Accessing a future object when using Python's Ipywidgets and Asyncio

Tags: python, concurrency, jupyter-notebook, python-asyncio, ipywidgets

I'm using Python's Asyncio library to create an interactive, 'stop-start' Notebook.
I am trying to run a section of code at a time, with proceeding sections utilising the previous input provided by a user.

For example, I have some code which uses Ipywidgets' file upload. I want my code to generate the upload button, 'stop' at this point, wait for a user to upload a CSV via the button, then for proceeding code to 'start' again (i.e. carry out processing steps on the CSV).

Thus far I've used the functions provided by the [Ipywidgets documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Asynchronous.html) to link the upload button with the uploaded object:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio

# Enable use of event loop in Jupyter Lab
nest_asyncio.apply()

# Initialise widgets
output = widgets.Output(clear_output=True)
upload = widgets.FileUpload()

@output.capture(clear_output=True)
def file_upload(widget):
    
    ''' Link change in widget value with the widget itself. '''
    
    future = asyncio.Future()
    
    @output.capture(clear_output=True)
    def on_value_change(change):
        
        ''' Get the 'change' in the widget value when the widget is updated. '''

        # Assign change in widget to future object
        future.set_result(widget.value)

        print('future result:', future.result())

        widget.unobserve(on_value_change)
    
    # Observed result - linking file upload button with the function used to extract the input
    widget.observe(on_value_change, names='value')
    
    return future
```

The issue I have is extracting the explicit file value (in a dictionary format) via the future object it's been assigned to.

When I run the following code:

```
display(upload, output)
asyncio.ensure_future(file_upload(upload))
```

I get the following result (printed to cell output after uploading the file):

```
future result: {'phone numbers for testing.csv': {'metadata': {'name': 'phone numbers for testing.csv', 'type': 'text/csv', 'size': 164, 'lastModified': 1632481950130}, 'content': b'Phone Numbers,,,,,\r\n07580026754,,,,,\r\n077896654312,,,,,\r\n+4456778763451,,,,,\r\n4487654367890,,,,,\r\n+44(0)765436217656,,,,,\r\n01685777444,,,,,\r\n+44(0)1652777666,,,,,\r\n'}}
```

The above object is correct - however I cannot seem to access this in the `main()` function used to run the code asynchronously, e.g the following code returns `<Future pending>` NOT `<Future finished>` (or the dictionary I need, accessed via `future.result()`):

```
async def main():
    file = asyncio.ensure_future(file_upload(upload))
    print(file)

display(upload, output)
asyncio.run(main())
```

I believe `asyncio.ensure_future()` schedules the coroutine as a task and runs it, whilst `asyncio.run()` starts/manages/stops the event loop, however I'm still very much learning about this library and how it operates. If anyone has any suggestions on how I can get the future in `main()` to become accessible so that I can perform subsequent processing, that would be greatly appreciated. There must be a way to do it without assigning it as a global variable?

Comment: You're partly right: ensure_future schedules the coroutine as a task.  But it does not run it.  No other task can run until the next await expression is encountered - asyncio is cooperative multitasking.  Try inserting `await file` after the ensure_future call.  Python will wait there until the future is done.

Comment: Thank-you for your reply Paul - i've tried what you said:

`async def main():
    file = asyncio.ensure_future(file_upload(upload))
    await file
    print(file)

display(upload, output)
asyncio.run(main())`

However the Jupyter Lab cell just keeps on running with no output printed to the cell. Is there something else I need to include after the await statement in order for it to finish?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Jupyter or IPython.  But I'm guessing that this is some sort of callback code (on_value_changed looks like a callback), and that might be your problem.  If you have a single-threaded program, an await expression will block the only thread.  That might prevent your callback from running.  I have tkinter programs that are callback-based, and a modified tkinter event loop is required for compatibility with asyncio.  I hope someone with more knowledge of your tools can help you.

Comment: It seems that the problem is exactly what @PaulCornelius guessed. I found a related [issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12786) on Github, which describes the problem that the awaited future is never completed.